# PHP: short syntax for set if not exists and increment

Tags: php

Is there a shorter syntax for the code below:

```
if (!isset($foo)) {
    $foo = $bar;
}
$foo += $bar;
```

**=== EDIT ===**

This syntax is slightly shorter:

```
isset($foo) ? $foo += $bar : $foo = $bar;
```

But I'm still wondering if it could be written in an even shorter way.

Comment: Why don't you know whether `$foo` is set or not? Initialise it to `0` at the top of the code block, done.

Comment: I'm using this syntax to create sub-arrays in a `foreach` statement and increment it. I can't see any reference to incrementation is the question mentioned, I doubt it's a duplicate, but I may have missed something.

Comment: If you want proper advice for your specific situation, you’ll have to show more code and not just a context-less snippet.

Comment: function increment(&$subject, $path, $amount=1){
            $keys = explode('.', $path);
            $ref = &$subject;
            $depth = count($keys);
            $i = 0;
            foreach($keys as $key){
                $i++;
                if($i < $depth) {if(!isset($ref[$key])) $ref[$key] = [];}
                else {if(!isset($ref[$key])) $ref[$key] = 0;}
                $ref = &$ref[$key];
            }
            $ref += $amount;
            unset($ref);
        }

        $subject = [];

        increment($subject, 'key1.key2', 5);

Comment: replace explode('.', $path) with explode('.', (string)$path) in the function above to prevent type error

Answer (score -2):

```
$foo = (!isset($foo))?0:$foo+$bar;
```

Try this.

Comment: Not the same operation, and still raises an error.

Comment: Updated my code.

Comment: This is much harder to read than the original question

Comment: @iainn The question was for a shorter way to write it. No-one ever asked for a prettier way to write it.

Answer (score -2):

You should never need to do this kind of check to begin with. Initialise your variables at the start of the program/function/block, and you rarely ever need `isset`:

```
$foo = 0;

// here be dragons

$foo += $bar;
```

Comment: The question wasn't "Should I do this" it was "How do I write an if statement shorter"

Comment: And the answer to "how to avoid shooting my face" is "don't point the gun at your head in the first place".

Comment: Using your own analogy, your answer to that question would be "Don't own a gun".

Comment: Also perfectly acceptable, yes.

Comment: Doesn't help someone if they already own the gun, and want to keep using it though, does it?

Comment: And now we're just squabbling about the semantics of an analogy. The point is, sometimes you need to fix a different issue than the one you're specifically asking about.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I agree with you. But you have no context for the question. There could be a very good reason for the way it's written. Or, you know, guy just wants to know how to use IF shorthand, and used a bad example. If you'd like to keep on this move it to chat, by all means.

Answer (score -3):

```
$foo = (!isset(foo) ? 0 : null);
$foo += $bar;
```

Or something to that effect. Ternary Operators for more information.

Comment: If `$foo` is set, you set it to `null`…? Not the same operation.